# Как выводить 0.25 как 0.250000?

Tags: c++, вывод, форматирование, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

У меня есть число типа `double`. Мне нужно, чтобы, если оно равно, скажем,  0.250000, при выводе эти завершающие нули не отбрасывались.

Answer (score 4):

Как я понимаю, вас интересует это при выводе числа? вы не сказали, как именно выводите - так что вот вам [два варианта](https://ideone.com/m4Dtdv):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    double a = 0.25;

    printf("%.6lf\n",a);

    cout << setprecision(6) << fixed << a << endl;

}
```